# Finding elements inside an iframe without a iframe id using robot framework

Tags: iframe, robotframework

HTML Looks like this

```html
<iframe src="/apex/cscfga__ConfigureProduct?linkedId=a0W8E000000Lpa5UAC&amp;configId=a0Z8E000000NBGMUA4&amp;retURL=/a0W8E000000Lpa5UAC&amp;isdtp=vw" width="100%" height="100%" onload="hideLoading()" frameborder="0" style="height: 737px;"></iframe>
```

Select frame doesnt work without id.How should my robot script recognise this iframe(without id)?

My script looks like

```
${Iframe}=  Execute Javascript  
window.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[2]
log ${Iframe}
```

But it returns 'None'

Please suggest how do I identify this iframe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Select Frame` will work with any type of locator. For example, if it's the only iframe on the page you can do this:

```
select frame    xpath=//iframe
```

If there are multiple iframes on the page, you need to try to find an ancestor that is uniquely identifiable and then look for the frame relative to that.

For example, given the following html:

```
<div class="spreadsheet_container">
    <div>
         <iframe ...>
```

... you can use an xpath such as the following:

```
select frame    xpath=//div[@class='spreadsheet_container']/div/iframe
```

Comment: @DISHAMUNSHI: if the answer helped you, consider voting for it and/or accepting it. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers